# New to React, OnClick not calling function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still in the process of learning React, I'm trying to implement an onClick function on a button element. The list of buttons are being rendered here:

```
    <div className="buttons">
      { colours.map((colour, index) => (
        <Button
          key={ index }
          onClick={() => this.checkChoice(colour)}
          className="button"
        >
          {colour}
        </Button>
      ))}
    </div>
```

And here is the onClick function I have already defined.

```
  checkChoice(col) {
    const {correctIndex, colours} = this.state;
    const newMessage = '';
    if (col == colours[correctIndex]){
      // correct colour chosen so update message
      newMessage = 'Correct!'
    } else {
      newMessage = 'Wrong!'
    }
    console.log(newMessage);
  }
```

I'm currently receiving no errors at all, however when I do click on a button, nothing is being printed to the console. Even when I try to call the function in the render method before returning, it still returns with nothing. I'm surely missing something silly, and would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

**Edit** Here is the Component code:

```
const Button = ({ onClick, className = '', children }) =>
  // {console.log(onClick)}
  <button
    onClick = { onClick }
    className = { className }
    type = "button"
  >
    { children }
  </button>
```

Comment: Make this an arrow function... `checkChoice = (col) => {...}` so that you don't have to bind for "this" ... and you can't reassign using `const` (newMessage) not sure why it's not showing an error right away ... Make it `let newMessage`

Comment: You probably need to bind your onclick handler in your class component constructor. Please post the full component code.

Comment: @MichaelAlanCohen I've just added the full component code

Comment: @KcH You're right, i'm not sure why using const did not throw an error outright, i imagine it's because the onClick function is never being called? I've used all your suggestions but i'm still in the same predicament.

Comment: @AlijaFajić That isn't very sound advice, it's like saying you shouldn't learn object-oriented programming because functional programming exists or that you shouldn't learn functional programming because object-oriented programming exists. Both have their use cases and are useful in different ways.

Comment: Can you share the full class, even if it was long, no problem, just omit the unrelated methods, I need to see the render method, and the constructor, and from which class in react you're extending?

Comment: this is most likely because you forgot to extend React.Component

Comment: @AlijaFajić I don't really agree, and I also don't see how that is relevant to the question at hand. If anything, only limiting your knowledge to one paradigm would narrow your prospects.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare "newMessage" variable using let or var. You can't reassign value to a variable declared with const. I have assumed correctIndex state as 1.

```
    import React from "react";
    
    const Button = ({ onClick, className = "", children }) => (
        // {console.log(onClick)}
        
            {children}
        
    );
    class Car extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                correctIndex: 1,
                colours: ["red", "green", "white"],
            };
        }
    
        checkChoice(col) {
            const { correctIndex, colours } = this.state;
            let newMessage = "";
            if (col == colours[correctIndex]) {
                // correct colour chosen so update message
                newMessage = "Correct!";
            } else {
                newMessage = "Wrong!";
            }
            console.log(newMessage);
        }
    
        render() {
            const { colours } = this.state;
            return (
                
                    {colours.map((colour, index) => (
                         this.checkChoice(colour)}
                            className="button"
                        >
                            {colour}
                        
                    ))}
                
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default Car;
```